# How to display the character `£` using c?

Tags: c, encoding, iso-8859-1

After referring the ISO 8859-1 standard, I get to know that the character `£` has the value `0xa3`, I want to display it using c, so I write this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf( "\\xa3 is: %c.\n", '\xa3' );
        printf( "£ is: %c.\n", '£' );

        return 0;
}
```

I save this source code file in iso 8859-1 encoding. And I hope my program to display `£` two times when `printf` meets each `%c`.

But, it does not work, why? How can I modify my program to achieve my goal.

I am using linux.

**EDIT:**

It's display is like this:

```
\xa3 is: �.
£ is: �.
```

Comment: Is your terminal set to ISO-8859-1?

Comment: _'But, it does not work'_ - what happens? How doesn't it work?

Comment: @deanWombourne, question updated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though your terminal is running in UTF-8 rather than 8859-1.  Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("\\xC2\\xA3 is: %s.\n", "\xC2\xA3");
    printf("£ is: %s.\n", "£");
    return 0;
}
```

On my Mac (where the terminal runs in UTF-8), the output is:

```
\xC2\xA3 is: £.
£ is: £.
```

Comment: Then, how to change my terminal runs in 8859-1?

Comment: Which terminal emulator under Linux are you using?  You can probably find a properties option on a menu, somewhere, and one of the properties will be the code set (related to, but different from, the font in use).

Comment: I am using Terminal 0.4.8, Xfce Terminal Emulator, I cannot find any menu item associated with encoding...

Comment: Judging from the manual for the [Xfce4 terminal](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/preferences) and the Preferences tab, choosing the codeset isn't an option.  If you need to use a different code set, you need to use a different terminal emulator.

Comment: A well-behaved program doesn't try to force an antiquated 8-bit character set upon its users. It respects the user's choice by being able to run in 8859-1, UTF-8, or any other encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the output terminal matches the [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) you've (randomly) chosen for this character. If you're using [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), but your terminal is expecting e.g. [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), you will probably get a result such as the one you're seeing.

Comment: Is there something called "run-time character set" of C language related to this problem?

Comment: Yes, there is a runtime environment which would include the character set.